# What's the best practice to speed-up query performance?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have a query which is taking 80 secs for 100 records joining 3 tables which is very bad performance,I am trying to figure out options to retrieve data much quickly?
I am going to use this query in my ASP.net web application and return an object with the corresponding fields.

Following is what I can think of?

1.Is there a better way to write this query?

2.If I split up the queries ,how-could-i-avoid-using-a-mysql-query-in-a-while-loop-in-php

```
select distinct spb.software_product_build,spb.date_created,spb.date_announced,ts.suite_name,ssr.MTBF,ssr.CPTH,ssr.TotalProductCrashes,ssr.TotalUniqueCrashes 

from software_product_builds spb 
inner join software_products sp on spb.software_product_id=sp.id     
inner join sp_default_variant spd on   spb.variant_id=spd.default_variant_id       
left join bit_sanity_results bsr on bsr.software_product_build_id=spb.software_product_build_id    
left join test_suites ts on bsr.test_suite_id=ts.id     
left join sns_sanity_results ssr on ssr.software_product_build_id=spb.software_product_build_id     
where sp.software_product='XXXX.LA.0.1' order by spb.software_product_build_id desc limit 100
```

Comment: use an analyser.

Comment: Add indexes for all columns in WHERE and ON clauses.  Order your JOINs to make the set as small as possible as quickly as possible.  You're doing five joins - what do you expect?  When you get to seven or more there's little you can do.  Bad design.  Once you've optimized as much as you can, you might have to denormalize.

Comment: @DanielA.White - how to use an analyzer?instructions or pointers?

Comment: @duffymo - do you have any pointers on how to get the data as quickly as possible? also If I split up the queries ,`how-could-i-avoid-using-a-mysql-query-in-a-while-loop-in-php `?

Comment: analyzer is called EXPLAIN PLAN.  Look for TABLE SCAN.

Comment: Pointers?  I just gave you three.  My best advice is to find a DBA who knows more about databases than you do.

Comment: There are no "best practices". Database performance is an expertise, this is why companies pays a fortune for a DBA. For the basics, follow the comments above, but don't expect us to teach you how to manage a database like a pro.

Comment: Guys way to be rude. This is why SO gets a bad rep.

Comment: Off topic Ryan. This is not about rudeness, this is about pragmatism. It is important for a developer to understand that databases are complex engines. Once you know that, you will train yourself to get better. But if nobody tells you, then you will never get better.

Answer (score 2):

You might like my presentation, [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video of me presenting it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

I can't tell only from reading your query what indexes you might already have defined, or what the relationships between your tables are. So it's a bit difficult to make the correct recommendation.

But for example, if you have a table `spb` and it's joining to table `sp`, for each row of `spb` it'll do a lookup to find the matching rows in `sp`. Having an index in `sp` will help that lookup.

```
from software_product_builds spb 
inner join software_products sp 
  on spb.software_product_id=sp.id
where sp.software_product='XXXX.LA.0.1'
```

In this case, you also have a constant lookup on the software_product column. So you can reduce the lookup to the subset of those matching rows.

```
ALTER TABLE software_products ADD INDEX (software_product, id);
```

This index will help reduce the search down to one row of that table. MySQL may even then decide to reverse the directory of the join because looking up one row in `sp` and then joining to the matching rows in `spb` might be the most efficient way.

On the other hand, you have `ORDER BY spb.software_product_build_id` so MySQL might prefer to use an index on that column so it can scan in index order instead of sorting the result. It can't do that unless it accesses the `spb` table first in the join order. So make sure you have an index:

```
ALTER TABLE software_product_builds ADD INDEX (software_product_build_id);
```

Then let MySQL figure out the most efficient path itself. It picks the best choice surprisingly often.

Likewise for other joins, you'd want to index the column that will be used for the lookups.

```
ALTER TABLE sp_default_variant ADD INDEX (default_variant_id);
ALTER TABLE bit_sanity_results ADD INDEX (software_product_build_id);
-- ALTER TABLE test_suites ADD INDEX (id);
ALTER TABLE sns_sanity_results ADD INDEX (software_product_build_id);
```

I commented out the one for `test_suites` because I assume its `id` column is the primary key, and that's already indexed implicitly. If the other cases already have indexes or if they are the primary key of the respective table, then skip creating new indexes.